# Is there a way to respec attributes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm pretty sure there isn't a way-explicitly-offered-by-the-game to unset and reinvest health, stamina, and/or magicka advancements, but I'm also curious about exploits, console commands, and/or mods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **[SkyTweak](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/33395)** mod allows editing of the player character attributes, including health, stamina, and magicka, and also many other game variables.

##### Attributes

[image: Changing Skyrim attributes through the SkyTweak mod]

##### Actor values

[image: Changing Skyrim actor values through the SkyTweak mod]

[Description of all game variables that SkyTweak can change.](https://web.archive.org/web/20220314092618/https://sites.google.com/site/grimyskyrim/my-mods/skytweak)

Answer (score 0):

There's no command to reset all your points, but you can de-spec and re-spec specific skills by using the console commands.

**player.removeperk XXXXX** removed the specific perk

**Player.Addperk XXXXX** adds specific perks

All the commands and perk codes are here http://www.carlsguides.com/walkthroughs/skyrim/resetperkscheat.php

There are also mods such as http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/16471/? which will give you in-game abilities to respec your perks.

Comment: The question is asking about health, stamina, and magicka, not skill points...

Comment: @unionhawk Ah, misread :D Updating

Answer (score 0):

showracemenu

> Bring up character customization menu. Magicka, Stamina, and Health will be spread evenly on using this depending on your character's level. It will remove any custom point distributions. Note: Using TGM command before entering the menu will retain your original levels. Will only modify your attributes/skills/points/etc. if you change the race, sex, or select a preset from the list. Modifying cosmetic things like skin color/warpaint/hair/face shape/etc. will leave your points.

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29

My testing:
Evenly distributes attributes and buffers a level up.
Using TGM beforehand prevents a level-up from being buffered. Changing race has the same effect. Changing sex has the same effect. Changing name has the same effect.

Bottom line: Use if the respec desired is to evenly distribute attributes.