# Light armor for more independent adventuring?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have all the DLCs for Skyrim.  I have leveled alchemy to 100 and have enchanting at 80 ( and will happily go to 100 for the purpose of armoring my mage properly).  I am playing a standard caster (conjurer/destruction), and would like to either craft my own armor and enchant it or enchant the Ancient Falmer armor (or something else if there is a "found" armor that is better).

My goal is to be less dependent on a follower tank or a thrall tank as I adventure.  Right now at level 46 the bandits pretty much one shot me in my Archmage robes unless I hide behind my tank or my thralls (which I don't mind up to a point, after all I am a mage).  I prefer to kill fast rather than  kite or survive via wards and armor spells so my goal is to have a bit more survivability via armor without making my character OP.
as opposed to full on alteration mitigation.

So:

### As a mage, should I craft my own armor? If so, should I craft light armor?

Right now I've gone the pure magicka route.  If I go the light armor route should I redistribute my attributes for more stamina?  If so do
I do that via the console or is there a legit way via something along
the line of the black book that permits me to change perks?

When I enchant my armor should I enchant for conjuration and
destruction or one or the other and magicka regen on the body?

Sorry for this book of a question.  This is my first post here so I'm not completely sure of the etiquette regarding length vs. background information.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Find some daedric armor. that works pretty well, though it is heavy armor. you could also work on your smithing level and make your own dragonscale or dragonplate armor.  Or you could just be a stealth archer and one shot everyone from the shadows with your bow and laugh as people are confused about how they are dying.

Comment: Hi, and welcome on Arqade ! Long posts are just fine when they are well-written, and it is better to provide enough information. That's a good first post :)

Comment: On second thought: you *might* have asked a bit too many questions at once. For the attributes part: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183253/is-there-a-way-to-respec-attributes

Comment: Thanks so much Ealhad :) Should I have asked the attribute question seperately or as a followup in this thread?

Comment: Don't forget to learn and cast the "flesh" spells, like Oakflesh. These increase your armor in the same way as actual armor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search claims that the light Dragonscale set would be your best bet if you're feeling a bit squishy. However, there are some other armors worth noting:

**Miraak's Robes**

With the other pieces of this set, you can get a lot of Magicka absorption.

**Vampire Royal Armor**

Found in the Castle Volkihar ruins, you should get some armor bonus from it, as well as increased Magicka regen.

Source: https://www.primagames.com/games/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/strategy/Skyrim-top-10-inventory-items-armor

Comment: Thanks for this reply Kaiserwolf.  All of it is very helpful and the link is super!  I think I will try the master vampire armor now.  I did go ahead and use the console to redistribute my magicka/health/stamina to 550 200 150 as per a suggestion for mage attributes on gamefaqs. I'm playing on master level currently and getting ready to fight Anduin ( hopefully with some pinache hehe).

Comment: Good luck then! The magicka regen will help a lot against a tank like Alduin.